# Forgot password in android using SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I implemented forgot password but i am getting an error. My db contains data.

Here is the logcat:

**"E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 8265
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean com.example.admin.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.updatepwd(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.admin.myapplication.Reset$1.onClick(Reset.java:39)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)"**

Below is the following code i have used:

Reset.java

```
public class Reset extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView phone;
EditText pwd,cpwd;
Button resetbtn;
 DatabaseHelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset);

        phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Phonenumber);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pssword);
        cpwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwdreenter);
        resetbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        phone.setText(intent.getStringExtra("phone"));
resetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
String user = phone.getText().toString();
                String pswd = pwd.getText().toString();
                String repswd = cpwd.getText().toString();

               if (pswd.equals(repswd)) {
                    Boolean pwd = db.updatepwd(user, pswd);
                    if (pwd) {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        Toast.makeText(Reset.this, "Password Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Reset.this, "Password NotUpdated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

//new code
public class MyTestDatabaseInstanceHolder {

    public MyTestDBHandler DBHelper;  
    public static SQLiteDatabase m_ObjDataBase; 

    public static void createDBInstance(Context pContext){
        if(DBHelper == null) {
            DBHelper = new WLDBHandler(pContext);
            m_cObjDataBase = DBHelper.openAndCreateDataBase(); 
        }
      }
}
```

Db.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "application.db";

    public static final String TABLE_SIGNUP = "Signup";

    public static final String COL_ID = "USER_ID";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_PHONE = "PHONE_NUMBER";
    public static final String COL_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String COL_CONFIRMPASSWORD = "CONFIRMPASSWORD";

    public static final String COL_NAMEone_CON = "NAMEONE";
    public static final String COL_NUMBERone_CON = "NUMBERONE";
    public static final String COL_NAMEtwo_CON = "NAMETWO";
    public static final String COL_NUMBERtwo_CON = "NUMBERTWO";
    public static final String COL_NAMEthree_CON = "NAMETHREE";
    public static final String COL_NUMBERthree_CON = "NUMBERTHREE";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
//        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SIGNUP + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
                + COL_NAME + " VARCHAR(255) , " + COL_PHONE + "  VARCHAR (255)  UNIQUE  ," + COL_EMAIL + " VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE," + COL_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR (255), "
                + COL_CONFIRMPASSWORD + " VARCHAR (255)," + COL_NAMEone_CON + " VARCHAR (255), "
                + COL_NUMBERone_CON + "  VARCHAR (255)  UNIQUE ," + COL_NAMEtwo_CON + " VARCHAR (255)," + COL_NUMBERtwo_CON + "  VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE , "
                + COL_NAMEthree_CON + " VARCHAR (255)," + COL_NUMBERthree_CON + " VARCHAR (255)  UNIQUE " + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SIGNUP);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    Boolean updatepwd(String PHONE_NUMBER, String PASSWORD) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
       long res=  db.update("Signup", contentValues, "PHONE_NUMBER  = ?", new String[]{PHONE_NUMBER});
        db.close();

        if(res == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your reference to `db` is `null`. Are you sure that you initialized it?

Comment: @AllanJuan  Yes i can login into my application just can't perform forgot password function

Comment: Well, the error message says you tried to invoke a method on a null reference. Please, do the following: Put a `System.out.println(db == null)` before calling `db.updateUser()`, just to be sure. After that, edit your post with the full stacktrace.

Comment: @AllanJuan Well, I didn't get you. Can you please explain or clarify it more?

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: @Henry I have posted logcat at beginning

Comment: The stacktrace shows that @AllanJuan is right, `db` is null at this point.

Comment: @Henry how to solve this i am confused.

Comment: Initialize `db` to an instance of class `Db`.

Comment: @Henry  Can you clarify it more please?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't know enough of your code. You must have an instance of `Db` somewhere.

Comment: @Henry  Should i post the whole code for you to guide as i am new to this so not able to understand.

Comment: You will learn more if you figure it out yourself.

Comment: @Henry    public class{  public DBHandler DBHelper;  
    public static SQLiteDatabase DataBase;                                                          
  public static void createDBInstance(Context pContext){
        if(DBHelper == null) {                                                                                                             DBHelper = new WLDBHandler(pContext);                                                                                 DataBase = DBHelper.openAndCreateDataBase();   }        }                                       
 Is this correct?

Comment: To include more code snippets, edit your post with them. It's hard to read code on comments

Comment: @AllanJuan I added the code in reset is that right

Comment: change  DatabaseHelper db; to  DatabaseHelper db =new DatabaseHelper(this);